# nnet in R, 'softmax = TRUE' requires at least two response categories

Tags: r, neural-network, softmax, nnet

I am trying to use nnet in R, and encounter a problem for using softmax.

I am trying to builda three layer network, with input layer have 25 neurons, hidden layer have 25 neurons, output layer only have one neuron. Here is how to reproduce the problem.

```
library('nnet')
X <- replicate(25, rnorm(40))
y <- sample(0:1,40,replace=T)

mynnet <- nnet(X, y, size = 25, 
                  softmax = T,
                  rang = 0.8, 
                  maxit = 2000, 
                  model=TRUE)
```

When I run this piece of code, I got a error:

```
Error in nnet.default(X, y, size = 25, 
softmax = T, rang = 0.8, maxit = 2000,  :
'softmax = TRUE' requires at least two response categories
```

What 'requires at least two response categories' means? And how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`softmax` is meant for fitting classification networks with a factor response variable. If you have a real-valued response, you probably want to fit a regression neural network, which can be obtained with `linout=TRUE`.